# Queries in access runtime return different result

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form with a few controls. The values entered into the controls are passed to the WHERE clause of a query I use to populate a list box on the same form.

Some of the columns that I am filtering on have null values. When the control is left empty, it should pull in all rows unfiltered by that column.

So part of my WHERE clause looks like this:

```
WHERE
(person.last_name like [Forms]![frmFilterPerson]![txtLastName] & "*"  
OR [Forms]![frmFilterPerson]![txtLastName] Is Null)
```

When I run my application in the full version of access, and I leave the txtLastName control blank, I get back ALL results, including the ones where the last name is null

However, when I run it in Access Runtime, I do not get all results, only the ones that have a value in the table for last name.

Any suggestions on how I can retrieve the rows that have null values while I have a filter in my where clause based on a control on my form?

Comment: I got trouble with a date criteria in runtime, solved it by using a parameter query or you can try `WHERE (((Nz(person.last_name,"") Like [Forms]![frmFilterPerson]![txtLastName] & "*")))`

Comment: There must be something else going on, the Access runtime doesn't evaluate query criteria differently then the full version.

Comment: @Andre Of course it does (it happend only once to me), but I checked the SQL-Code  with a `MsgBox` and it  showed correct and worked fine copy and pasted into full-version (also with /runtime parameter). I will look it up and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this old trick - comparing the field with itself:

```
WHERE 
    person.last_name Like Nz([Forms]![frmFilterPerson]![txtLastName], person.last_name) & "*" 
    OR
    person.last_name Is Null
```

Or:

```
WHERE 
    person.last_name Like Nz([Forms]![frmFilterPerson]![txtLastName], person.last_name) & "*" 
    OR
    [Forms]![frmFilterPerson]![txtLastName] Is Null
```

Comment: What is the advantage compared to `Nz(person.last_name,"")`? The still availible index of `person.last_name`?

Comment: Doesn't work for my testdata (no Null values are shown). Is something missing?

Comment: I didn't care for _Null_ values. I've edited the answer to do that.

Comment: @BitAccesser: I read it as if `[Forms]![frmFilterPerson]![txtLastName]` was _Null_ all values should be returned.

Comment: Looks good, if he always wants `Null`data returned, not sure if he only wants `Null`data when textbox is empty.

Comment: This sort of works, but not quite. Now, when I search for the last name "Smith", it returns the Smiths AND all rows where last_name is null. When I enter a filter value, I want it to only return the rows that match the filter criteria, it's just when I leave the text box empty, that it should include both rows with actual and null values. Any thoughts?

Comment: @BitAccesser, just saw your comment here and above. Your answer works the way I need it to. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I am the greatest (from a reciprocal point of view). Maybe @Gustav knows a better solution, because mine can't make use of an index.

Comment: @BitAccesser: Nz should be fine if not millions of records. Or check out my appended alternative.

Comment: But your second criteria-string is better, one shouldn't use the second best solution, as it can cause headache in future, without any needs (I've been biten a lot, by shortcuts done in the past). But we missed the original topic: is there still a difference between Runtime and Full-Version?

Comment: There shouldn't be. I've only seen trouble when referencing ActiveX and other libraries.

Comment: I don't have any references enabled, other than VBA, OLE Automation and the Access and Office Object Libraries. The tables are hosted on SQL Server and I connect to them via an ADO connection. Not sure if that would make a difference. Either way, thanks for you guys' help!